# 3D Data preparation and data spliting for model training and testing

Tags: python, deep-learning

I am working with CNN2D and I have feature as array of 7904 log mel spectrogram i.e. matrix of size 128 x 251. So x is array of size (7904 x (128 x 251 ))

The link for the program is https://colab.research.google.com/drive/17P9-tI6pCvaCRbXdhzM3-gW58-2Txp9m?usp=sharing

```
X, Y = [], []
# X = feature  Y = emotion
for path, emotion in zip(data_path.path, data_path.emotion):
    feature = get_features(path)
    for ele in feature:
        X.append(ele)
        # appending emotion 3 times as we have made 3 augmentation techniques on each audio file.
        Y.append(emotion)
```

```
def split_data(X, Y):
    from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, OneHotEncoder
    from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, classification_report
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

    x = np.array(X)
    y = np.array(Y)
    # splitting data
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, random_state=0,test_size=0.2, shuffle=True)
    x_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(x_train, y_train,random_state=0,test_size=0.2, shuffle=True)
    return x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test

x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test = split_data(X, Y)
```

here feature is having 4 matrix which represents log mel spectrogram with size 128x251.

```
NameError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-4494e8ad8639> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 best_run, best_model = optim.minimize(model=model,
      2                                           data=split_data,
      3                                           max_evals=10,
      4                                           algo=tpe.suggest,
      5                                           notebook_name='robust_ser', # This is important!

2 frames
/content/temp_model.py in <module>
    211 from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    212 
--> 213 x = np.array(X)
    214 y = np.array(Y)
    215 # splitting data

NameError: name 'X' is not defined
```

Is there any other way to store those features to train the model or to resolve the above error?

Comment: `NameError: name 'X' is not defined` your variable is not in scope.  This isn't a deep-learning problem, it's just a variable definition problem.  Googling this error should give lots of advice.